# Why can I not use this generic as a parameter with seemingly the same bounds?

Tags: java, generics

I have a constructor and a method.

The constructor takes a parameter `List<Class<? extends CalculatorOperation>> operationLists"` and then uses it as a parameter for my second method named "mapOperations()."

mapOperations() accepts a parameter `List<Class<E>> operationLists` where `<E extends CalculatorOperation>`

To me, these seem to be the same bounds, but I'm given an error that says the argument is not applicable. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `<? extends CalculatorOperation>` means any subclass of `CalculatorOperation`, for example A or B.  `<E extends CalculatorOperation>` means a certain subclass of `CalculatorOperation`, only A or only B. In your code,  first method return value says I have a set of A and B(Three situations: set of A, set of B, set of A and B), but your second method says I only can accept a set of A or a set of B, I don't know the certain type of you(consider the three possible return value's type), so I refused.Hope you can understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    doSomething(List.of(Integer.class, Double.class));      // Compiles fine
    doSomethingAgain(List.of(Integer.class, Double.class)); // Does NOT compile
}

static void doSomething(List<Class<? extends Number>> list) {

}

static <T extends Number> void doSomethingAgain(List<Class<T>> list) {

}
```

This occurs because `T extends Number` only expects a single child of `Number` (we specified `Integer.class` first, so that's what the method expects) whereas `? extends Number` expects any combination of child classes of `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. You can:

```
List<Class<? extends Animal>> animalTypes = new ArrayList<>();
animalTypes.add(Dog.class);
animalTypes.add(Cat.class);
```

But you cannot:

```
List<Class<T>> animalTypes = new ArrayList<>(); // Where class defines T extends Animal
animalTypes.add(Dog.class);
animalTypes.add(Cat.class);
```

This is because case 1 accepts any `Class` that is extended from `Animal`. Case 2 accepts *one* particular class that extends from `Animal`. If your class defines T as `Dog`, then the list can only hold classes of `Dog` type.